# How can I let the user install the same application in 2 different locations

Tags: windows-installer, install4j

I've made a installer for a Java application and wrapped it as an Windows MSI package. It is possible to install it multiple times at different locations with some other configuration options.

However when the user runs the uninstaller more than once (i.e uninstalling MyAppInFolder1, MyAppInFolder2) the user will get this error message:

"This Action is Only Valid for Products that are Currently Installed"

This means that the user never will be able to get rid of (as an example) C:\Program Files\MyAppInFolder2.

What is controlling this check? Is there any solution this this issue?

Comment: What version of install4j do you use?

Comment: How you're installing it multiple times? Windows installer checks for upgrade code, product code if its already installed. Are you trying to update it?

Comment: I'm using 10.0.4.

Comment: @VivekJaiswal 

I was wrapping the app in an MSI installer which seem to have this control.

If I'm not wrapping as an .MSI, running the installer a second time just ask if I want to update the currently installed version or install it to a new location.

Answer (score 0):

The control point of whether or not a "Product" is installed origins from whether or not the installer is wrapped as an .MSI or not.

If the installer isn't wrapped in an .MSI this is not an issue.